# Why can't you run a teleportation circuit on an IBM Q device?

Tags: ibm-q-experience, teleportation

I'm studying teleportation circuits with [this tutorial](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/community/terra/qis_intro/teleportation_superdensecoding.ipynb) and just out of curiosity, why can't a teleportation circuit be run on an IBM Q device?

Comment: I believe it has to do with binary controlled operations which aren't supported (I'm not sure about this) bij QISKit. Hence, quantum teleportation is not possible.

Comment: It should be possible to run a modified teleportation circuit, in which you defer the measurements until the end of the circuit and replace classically controlled gates by quantum controlled gates. Haven't tried it on IBM Q, but on a simulator it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked someone from IBM and got this answer:
Teleportation can not be run on the IBM Q devices at the moment as no operations can be performed after a measurement.